# nightwatch stuck on starting selenium server

Tags: node.js, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, nightwatch.js

I'm using nightwatch.js to test website.
2 days ago, It worked, but since tomorrow It didn't work.
When I'm trying to test with `$ nightwatch <test_file>` (because I installed nightwatch globally. and It worked for a month.), It shows `Starting selenium server...` and don't anything.
using `--verbose` doesn't show anything else. It also just shows `Starting selenium server...` 
I updated chromedriver, nightwatch and npm, but same.

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS, amd64
chromedriver_linux64.zip
nightwatch 0.9.14
selenium-server-standalone-3.3.1

this is my nightwatch.json

```
{
  "src_folders" : ["tests/e2e"],
  "output_folder" : "tests/reports",
  "custom_commands_path" : "tests/custom",
  "custom_assertions_path" : "",
  "page_objects_path" : "",
  "globals_path" : "",
  "selenium" : {
    "start_process" : true,
    "server_path" : "./bin/selenium-server-standalone-3.3.1.jar",
    "log_path" : "tests/logs",
    "host" : "127.0.0.1",
    "port" : 4444,
    "cli_args" : {
      "webdriver.chrome.driver" : "./chromedriver",
      "webdriver.ie.driver" : ""
    }
  },
  "test_settings" : {
    "default" : {
      "launch_url" : "http://localhost",
      "selenium_port"  : 4444,
      "selenium_host"  : "localhost",
      "silent": true,
      "screenshots": {
        "enabled" : true,
        "on_failure" : true,
        "on_error" : false,
        "path" : "tests/screenshots"
      },
      "desiredCapabilities": {
        "browserName": "chrome",
        "javascriptEnabled": true,
        "acceptSslCerts": true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved it.
It was because selenium-standalone-server process was still running on.
I killed it, and test works.

Answer (score 1):

Similarly, this happened to me due to a port collision. If some other process is running on 4444, Selenium wont start, and Nightwatch doesn't tell you the error.

Changing, the port to 4445, in nightwatch.json, fixed it for me: 

`"selenium" : {
     ...
    "port" : 4445,`